# Total and partial derivatives of $F(T, X(Y, Z))$ respect to $T$?

Tags: vector-analysis, differential

So, yeah, haven't been to vector analysis just yet, but for now I'd need to make sure I understand the definition of total derivatives (and partial derivatives).

The question is simple. I wish to take $\frac{dF}{dT}$ when $F = F(T, X(Y,Z))$ so that Y and Z might depend on T.

And just to check that I understand the rule correctly, what is $\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}$? Do I always have to specify which variable I keep constant when taking the partial derivative - I somehow undestood that when taking a partial derivative it didn't matter, as you only take derivatives respect to *explicit dependence*, and that's it. 
But then I've seen the use of $(\frac{\partial F}{\partial T})_{X}$, say. What does that mean?

It would be awesome if someone could clarify =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use chain rule over and over:
$$
\frac {dF}{dT} = \frac {\partial F}{\partial T} + \frac {\partial F}{\partial X} \frac {\partial X}{\partial T} = \frac {\partial F}{\partial T} + \frac {\partial F}{\partial X} \left( \frac {\partial X}{\partial Y} \frac {\partial Y}{\partial T} +  \frac {\partial X}{\partial Z} \frac {\partial Z}{\partial T}\right ) \tag {*}
$$
Best way to check it is direct calculations. So, for example, let's say you have a function $F(T, X) = T^2 + \sin X$, but $X(Y,Z) = Y^5 + \frac 1Z$, $Y = \log T$ and $Z = \exp T$, so $$
F = T^2 + \sin \left( \log^5 T - \exp T\right)
$$
Total derivation means that you find derivative of $F$ with respect to $T$ when you reduce all other arguments to $T$ only, like I did above. So
$$
\frac {dF}{dT} = 2T + \cos \left( \log^5 T - \exp T\right) \left(\frac{5 \log^4 T}T - \exp T\right )
$$
On the other hand $\frac {\partial F}{\partial T}$ means partial derivative, i.e. when all other arguments are considered constant. So, for the example above
$$
\frac {\partial F}{\partial T} = 2T
$$
In your case, you have a function of two variables only (initially), so
$$
\left (\frac {\partial F}{\partial T} \right)_X \equiv \frac {\partial F}{\partial T}
$$

Comment: Thank you! 
About the last notation - in what (type of, as with what kind of function) type of case $(\frac{\partial F}{\partial T})_X$ is not equal to $\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}$?

Comment: To clarify: since you said (and this is also how I've undestood it) "..when all other arguments are considered constant". This is why I fail to see what new information is in the notation $(\frac{\partial F'}{\partial T})_X$ (note that here I haven't defined F')

Comment: Because to me the last notation sounds a bit like taking the total derivative first, and then defining one of the arguments to be constant and writing the final result accordingly. But I'm not sure, and I find the notation a bit confusing.

Comment: @souf other notation usually is used in physics mostly, in statistical physics if to be exact. It is the same as simple partial derivative, but instead you explicitly specify what variables are constant, which variable is a function of other ones, etc. Take a look to this paper, for example [link](http://mutuslab.cs.uwindsor.ca/schurko/introphyschem/handouts/mathsht.pdf)

Comment: Hmm, yeah, so I've gathered. 
Now that i've been thinking about this over, if you have a function F(T, Y, X(T,Y)) say, it doesn't seem so trivial to try to take a partial derivative respect to T - how could you in this case keep both X and Y constant?

Comment: @souf you just don't expand your function, and leave $T$, $X$ and $Y$ as they are, and take partial w.r.t. $T$. If you mean second, alternative, notation, all those variable but one are independent with some constraint on their combination. For example, in thermodynamics $P,V,T$ are main variables, but they are connected by the equation of state. So, you can keep two constant out of three. If you need other way around, you just change your function in such a way (something like finding inverse) that other two still independent. Sorry for my writing, I know it looks messy.

Comment: Thank you for keeping on the conversation =)

I'm not convinced that you can keep 2 out of 3 as constants. Think about an ideal gas in a piston. Say we heat it - now it either wants to expand or its pressure goes up, according to PV = RT [I took 1 mol of the gas]. By changing T it is clear that PV i.e. both P and V cannot stay as constants.

I believe that in a situation G = G(T,X(T,Y)) it is possible to keep X as a constant, even though it depends on T. But in this case, I think we'd have to move y to the opposite direction than T.